# Ember rendering into outlet within named outlet

Tags: ember.js, outlet

Given these templates

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h3>Application outlet:</h3>
  <div class="outlet">
    {{outlet}}
  <div>

  <h3><code>'base'</code> outlet:</h3>
  <div class="outlet base-outlet">
    {{outlet 'base'}}
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <h1>I am the application index, I should be in the application outlet.</h1>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="foo">
  <p>I am foo, I have my own outlet here:</p>
  <h3>Foo Outlet:</h3>
  <div class="outlet foo-outlet">  
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="foo/index">
  <p>I am foo index, I should be inside <code>#foo-outlet</code> (green border)</p>
</script>
```

And these routes:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('foo', function() {
    this.resource('bar');
  });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 
  afterModel: function() {
    this.transitionTo('foo.index');
  }
});

App.FooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render({into: 'application', outlet: 'base'});
  }
});
```

I would expect the `foo/index` template to be rendered inside the `{{outlet}}` contained in the `foo` template, however it is rendered into the applications outlet, there is a live example here: http://jsbin.com/yecatu/6/edit?html,js,output

Note if I put a call to `this._super()` in `renderTemplate` I get the `foo/index` sort of in the right place, but the `foo` template is rendered twice.

**Update:** What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

1. Application has a named outlet, let's say `'sidebar'`
2. A route can render a wrapper into this sidebar outlet which contains its own (unnamed) outlet
3. Then sub routes of that route should render in the outlet within the wrapper.

So in the above example the `foo` route should be rendering its wrapper into the `'base'` outlet, then the content of its sub routes (`foo/index` in the example) should be rendered within the outlet inside that wrapper (the one with the class `foo-outlet` in the example).

Comment: I think if you are using the `data-template-name` attribute you have to specifically tell the view in charge to use this template then (`templateName` http://emberjs.com/guides/views/inserting-views-in-templates/). You might just want to use the `id` attribute in the template definition to have ember-naming-convention-automatic-magic-stuff in place. I would also call the `super` with parameters always, don't know if that changes anything in that case though. Get yourself a working example app to follow designpatterns for a smooth start, use ember-cli from the beginning as well ;) good luck!

Comment: Making those changes doesn't make any difference, I still get it almost working but with that weird double rendering thing if I add the call to super, see http://jsbin.com/yecatu/7/edit

Comment: Maybe this is more like what you actually want and gives you an idea of how things work together: http://jsbin.com/zakuwexuwu/3/edit If that doesn't help, I don't understand the question ;)

Comment: @Preexo no that doesn't help, I've added an update to my question to try and clarify. 

The most confusing thing to me is why when I call `_super()` in the `renderTemplate` I get the `foo/index` rendering in the right place but get the `foo` template rendered twice. I assume the call to `_super()` is doing the normal rendering into the applications unnamed outlet, but that doesn't explain why doing that triggers `foo/index` to be rendered into the outlet as I want.